# Convert value depending on a type in SparkSQL via case matching of type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to match a parametric type in Scala? Lets say I have a function that receives two parameters: a `value` and a `type`. I would like to use pattern matching to do a type conversion.

Something like this:

```
datatype match {
  case IntegerType => return value.toInt
  case FloatType => return value.toFloat
  case StringType => return value
  case DecimalType(_,_) => return BigDecimal(value) // this is not working
  case _ => return strrepr
}
```

Here `DecimalType` accepts two parameters to specify precision the required precision. It can be for example:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType = DecimalType(10,2)
```

I have tried several options and nothing seems to be working:

- For **`case DecimalType => return BigDecimal(value)`** I get:

  ```
  error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
     found   : org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.type
     required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
     Note: if you intended to match against the class, try `case DecimalType(_,_)`
  ```
- For **`case DecimalType(_,_) => return BigDecimal(value)`** I get:

  ```
  error: result type Boolean of unapply defined in method unapply in object DecimalType does not conform to Option[_] or Boolean
  ```
- For **`case DecimalType[_,_] => return BigDecimal(value)`** I get:

  ```
  error: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType does not take type parameters
  ```

Comment: What is DecimalType? If you mean [org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType), it does not look like a parametric type to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the use of the `return` in your code. You said you use this code snippet in a function somewhere. What is the return type of that function? Obviously, you intend that sometimes it is Integer, sometimes String, sometimes BigDecimal; but if you use `return`, it will look to the type of the returned object to determine the return type of the function.  In general, you should strongly avoid using `return` in Scala code. The last evaluated value in the function body is returned. The only case for using a `return` is when you want to force returning a value somewhere else in the function body. But still, a better way would be to save the return object in a variable and just evaluate that variable in the last line of your function body. And never use return!

**Without `return` it works**

```
scala> val datatype = DecimalType(10, 2)
datatype: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType = DecimalType(10,2)

scala> val value = BigDecimal(10)
value: scala.math.BigDecimal = 10

scala> datatype match {case DecimalType(_,_) => value}
res150: scala.math.BigDecimal = 10
```

** Problems with return **

```
scala> def test = {datatype match {case DecimalType(_,_) => return value}}
<console>:138: error: method test has return statement; needs result type
       def test = {datatype match {case DecimalType(_,_) => return value}}

scala> def test:BigDecimal = {datatype match {case DecimalType(_,_) => return value}}
test: BigDecimal

scala> def test:DataType = {datatype match {case DecimalType(_,_) => return value}}
<console>:138: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.math.BigDecimal
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
       def test:DataType = {datatype match {case DecimalType(_,_) => return value}}

scala> def test3 = {datatype match {case DecimalType(_,_) => value}}
test3: scala.math.BigDecimal
```

Comment: KrisP, thanks for your answer. The problem was not with the return -- I suspect the datatype the function was getting was not an object DataType(10,2) but rather a class reference. Something like ``org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType$@40ff96ee``. Your code is working perfectly, I misunderstood the parameter the function was getting (I'm new to scala and spark). Thanks for the help. Here is what worked in the end:  ``case  _ : DecimalType => return BigDecimal(value)``. At the same time, it is still a mystery to me why it was working with other class types..

Answer (score 8):

Turns out that DecimalType only pattern matches with zero arguments:

```
  case DecimalType() => ...
```

If you need the precision and scale, you must define the type of the case and manually extract them:

```
datatype match {
  case dt: DecimalType =>
    val precision = dt.precision
    val scale = dt.scale
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be something specific to the code I'm working on, or perhaps it varies depending on the SQL vendor, but I found that `DecimalType` doesn't have a single underlying type. Sometimes I get a spark `Decimal` and other times I get a java `BigDecimal`. If I try to `getAs[Decimal]` when it's a `BigDecimal`, I get an exception. If I try to `getAs[BigDecimal]` when it's a `Decimal`, I get an exception.

To handle this I had to do some more sniffing after matching `DecimalType`:

```
  case d: DecimalType =>
    // Oddly a column that matches to DecimalType can be of several different
    // class types and trying to getAs[Decimal] when it's a BigDecimal and/or
    // trying to getAs[BigDecimal] when the column is a Decimal results in an
    // exception, so make the right decision based on the instance class.
    val decimal = row.get(index) match {
      case bigDecimal: java.math.BigDecimal => Decimal(bigDecimal)
      case decimal: Decimal => decimal
      case _ => throw(
        new RuntimeException("Encountered unexpected decimal type")
      )
    }
```

From there you can do whatever you need to do knowing that `decimal` is of type `Decimal`.